# Variable outside of the function nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

how can I get data from a variable outside of the function? 
Below is the code, in the comments I put a description of what I mean.

```
var url = 'http://localhost/cron/temp.php';

request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
  }, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    } else {
      // data is already parsed as JSON:
      console.log(data);

      var temp = data; // This var

    }
});


 console.log(temp); // How to get here?
```

Comment: you can't get it outside of the function, you'll either need to work with it inside your function, use a callback function and pass it as an argument, or use a Promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work

```
 console.log(temp); // How to get here?
```

because requesting the data from a site `request.get` take some time, this is an asynchronous call. We don't know when the request will complete. So the javascript engine starts executing the statement next to `request.get` which is `console.log(temp); // How to get here?` and at that time `temp` has not been defined.

The correct way to do this is create a function that will do the task that you want to do with your data. Like:

```
const printData = (data) => {
   console.log(data)
}
```

and call this function inside the callback of `request.get`. Where you have access to `data`.